# Doing if statement below a cell that has the string "gross rate" on it?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

The cell positioning always changes.

Everyday I get the same report, and I want to run a condition that says:

> If value below the cell with the text string "gross"is  over 100, then increase 5% and round to the nearest dollar.
> If value below the cell with the text string "gross" is 125 increase 10% and round to the nearest dollar.

The code that I have right now:

```
Sub test()
Dim c
With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z500")
    Set c = .Find("Gross", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        If c.Offset(1, 0).Value >= 100 Then
            c.Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(c.Offset(1, 0).Value * 1.05, 0)
        ElseIf c.Offset(1, 0).Value >= 125 Then
            c.Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(c.Offset(1, 0).Value * 1.1, 0)
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

But I can't seem to make it so that it runs on every value below that cell until it hits a blank one. How would I do that?

Comment: It would be useful to know where this "Gross" could be found. Is it in a specific column or could it be anywhere in the sheet? Does it only show up once?
When you said `is 125 increase 10%` do you mean if it's 125 or more or just 125? What if it's less than 100? Please ensure to provide all information you can about your problems, otherwise how can we help, although you have no code for us to help with.

Comment: Think about how you would do that manually (eg using find) and then give the macro recorder a try to get a first idea how this could work. Note that the recorded macro will need adjustments but it will help you to start. Give it a try and come back with what you have tried ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)) and tell where you got stuck or errors.

Comment: Hey simon! The value just randomly changes in every report so I'd like code that can perform an if function on every value below the gross value until it hits a spwce. I'd like it to be 125 or more aswell, if it's less than 100 I'd like to leave it alone. Thank you so much for your time I just have no idea how to get started writing this one lol

Comment: Sub test()
    Dim c
    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z500")
        Set c = .Find("Gross", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            If c.Offset(1, 0).Value >= 100 Then
                c.Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(c.Offset(1, 0).Value * 1.05, 0)
            ElseIf c.Offset(1, 0).Value >= 125 Then
                c.Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(c.Offset(1, 0).Value * 1.1, 0)
            End If
        End If
    End With
    End Sub
    
Maybe something like this? But how can I make it so that it continues to run that code until it hits a blank line?

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I introduced `While` loop.

```
Sub test()
Dim c
Dim i as Long
With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z500")
    Set c = .Find("Gross", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        i = 1
        Do While c.Offset(i, 0).Value <> ""
            If c.Offset(i, 0).Value >= 125 Then
                c.Offset(i, 0).Value = Round(c.Offset(i, 0).Value * 1.1, 0)
            ElseIf c.Offset(1, 0).Value >= 100 Then
                c.Offset(i, 0).Value = Round(c.Offset(i, 0).Value * 1.05, 0)
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End If
End With
End Sub
```